# How to make the dtype parameter of to_sql command pull from a dictionary

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, dtype

I tried to make the dtype parameter of the to_sql command pull from a JSON file I get the error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value". Is there a way to do this?

Instead of the below code:

```
import sqlalchemy 

resource_read.to_sql(tablename,engine,  schema = None,  if_exists='append',  dtype={'ID': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50),  'NAME': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255)})
```

I want to do something like this where the dtype dictionary parameter is a key value pair in a json file:
the config json file would look like this:

```
{
    "dtypes": {"ID": sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50), "NAME": sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255) }
}
```

Then the code is:

```
import sqlalchemy

config_path = os.path.join("C:\configs")

my_parser.add_argument('-c','-configname', dest='configname', help="Configname file")

args = my_parser.parse_args()          

if args.configname:         
   with open(os.path.join(config_path, args.configname), 'r') as f:           
       config_params = json.load(f)

resource = os.path.join(resource_path, filename)

resource_read = pd.read_csv(resource, encoding='utf8', na_values='', dtype=str)

resource_read.to_sql(tablename,engine,schema = None,if_exists='append',dtype=config_params["dtypes"])
```

The issue is that the value for the dictionaries in the dtypes key is not in quotes, when I put it in quotes I don't get the JSON issue but I get a sqlalchemy error:

> ValueError: The type of ID is not a SQLAlchemy type

Do I somehow convert the value to non-quotes when reading them in?
If I just put in the dictionary within the script and I don't put quotes around the values I don't get an error and it runs fine. But I want it in a json file.

Comment: *it doesn't work* ... please be specific. Any errors or undesired results? Can't see how the two lines should differ with Python's interpreter. Try running again for reproducibility.

Comment: hi I just updated my question above. Thank you.

Comment: Please show how `config` is assigned even if it means reading from a `.json` file. We want to be able to reproduce your issue. Not clear what you mean by quotes.

Comment: Hi, I added more info. Sorry, I didn't realize you needed that information. Hopefully I covered everything now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hmmmm...that is not a valid JSON and should raise an error when parsing. Specifically, on `json.load(f)` line, I get `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value`. Please post sample of actual JSON if you do not get this error.

Comment: yea it does error, that's why I had to add the double quotes I was mentioning earlier which you said wasn't clear. But the double quotes just fixes the json but doesn't run sqlalchemy. I read your solution and will try it the way you described and let you know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming actual JSON quotes the `sqlalchemy` types:

```json
{
    "dtypes": {"ID": "sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50)", "NAME": "sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255)" }
    
}
```

An immediate solution is to call `eval` in a dict comprehension to build `dtypes` dictionary. But **warning**: use this powerful function with caution and not open to unknown user input.

```py
sql_dtypes = { k:eval(v) for k,v in config_params['dtypes'].items() }

print(sql_dtypes)
# {'ID': VARCHAR(length=50), 'NAME': VARCHAR(length=255)}

...

resource_read.to_sql(tablename,engine,schema = None,if_exists='append', dtype=sql_dtypes )
```

---

Alternatively, if you have ability to adjust config file, consider saving its underlying types and attributes and not any Python module variables. (See added `DECIMAL` type for demonstration.)

```json
{
    "dtypes": {
               "ID": ["VARCHAR", 50], 
               "DATE": ["DATETIME"],
               "NAME": ["VARCHAR", 255], 
               "VALUE": ["DECIMAL", 10, 6]
              }
    
}
```

Then, you can call `sqlalchemy.types` dynamically with `getattr` (nested for additional attributes of `types`) and pass needed parameters.

```py
sql_dtypes = { k: getattr(getattr(sqlalchemy, 'types'), v[0])(v[1] if len(v) >= 1 else None, 
                                                              v[2] if len(v) >= 2 else None)
                        for k,v in config_params['dtypes2'].items() }

print(sql_dtypes)
# {'ID': VARCHAR(length=50), 'DATE': DATETIME, 'NAME': VARCHAR(length=255), 'VALUE': DECIMAL(precision=10, scale=6)}

...

resource_read.to_sql(tablename,engine,schema = None,if_exists='append', dtype=sql_dtypes )
```

Comment: wow I would never have known to go about it this way, thank you so much. I will test this out and let you know.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!

Comment: Hi I was able to test it out and it works great, one thing I am not sure how to handle are DateTime() dtypes. How do I save that in the json "end_date": ["DateTime"] ?

Comment: also when you write in the code to check if the length is 2 and if it's not then grab the third element in v, when is that actually used and what is it applicable for to add a third element in the json? so that it works for datetime should I change it to say "else v[0]" ? Thank you!

Comment: Usually datetimes would not have additional args so do not include in `json` and then in Python check if length is 1 in the first argument of outermost `getattr`. Reversed [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) to read better. See edit.